# Flutter Provider and initState / Mapping list of widgets

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to covert the list `names` stored in my `DataProivder` into a list of widgets called `nameSlots`, as shown below. Ideally when I update / add to the list `names` it will also update the list of widgets `nameSlots`.

However, the method I'm using encounters errors. How do I create a list of widgets from my `names` list that will update?

**data_provider.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DataProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  List<String> _names;
  List<String> _games;

  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();

  DataProvider() {
    _names = [];
    _games = ["Game 1", "Game 2", "Game 3", "Game 4", "Game 5"];
  }

  // Getters
  List<String> get names => _names;
  List<String> get games => _games;

  // Setters
  void setNames(List<String> names) {
    _names = names;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setGames(List<String> games) {
    _games = games;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  addToList() {
    if (nameController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      names.add(nameController.text);
      nameController.clear();
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
}
```

**machine_test.dart**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../providers/data_provider.dart';

class MachineTest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MachineTestState();
  }
}

class _MachineTestState extends State<MachineTest> {
  List<Widget> nameSlots;
  List<Widget> gameSlots;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    var dataProvider = Provider.of<DataProvider>(context);

    nameSlots = dataProvider.names
        .map(
          (names) => Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  names,
                  textScaleFactor: 1.2,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                Image.asset(
                  "assets/images/4.png",
                  width: 30,
                  height: 30,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            width: 50,
            height: 70,
          ),
        )
        .toList();
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Hi Nae, I've made some edits to try and make it clearer. Hope this helps!